# ms-access email electronic signiture

Tags: ms-access

I wish to be able to send Microsoft access report as PDF file, to a client and request them to electronically sign documentation derived from the PDF form. Is there any way of incorporating adobe  reader! With Microsoft access reports as PDF and send them as emails.

An example would be, I send a financial report to the client, in which they need to sign. I would do this by emailing the report as a PDF file requesting an  electronic signature. It would be nice if I was able to automate this process to Microsoft Access under the clients name. Therefore  would appreciate if anyone has any idea how to achieve this, and who they are the examples?
Thanks

To get electronic signature from the client

Comment: Adobe reader cannot alter PDF files. Client can use on-line digital signature service such as https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/sign-pdf.html. Include link in email.

Comment: Adrian, there are whole services who do nothing, but provide a paid service to electronically sign documents. I highly doubt this can be achieved with MS Access, not to mention this requires much more technical knowledge than "can I use Adobe Reader"